# How to find length of an array of objects from ReactJS setState?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm not able to find/print the length of an array of objects that set by ReactJS `setState`. My component.js is as follows

```
import React from 'react';

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          loading: true,
          error: false,
          items: []
        };
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/v2/pages/1')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => this.setState({ items: data }));
    }

    render() {
        console.log(this.state.items.content.length); // Gives error that says this.state.items is not defined
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
}

export default MyComponent;
```

When I console log `this.state.items` I get the following object

```
{
    "id": 12,
    },
    "title": "My Title",
    "content": [
        {
            "type": "full_richtext",

            "id": "6e971101"
        },
        {
            "type": "button",
            "id": "c0f6083d"
        }
    ]
}
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to get the length of the array 'content' within inside the object set by `setState`.

**Back Story:**

My goal is to handle the asynchronous nature of `setState` by writing a condition like following inside `render()`

```
if(this.state.items.content.length > 0){
  //access values from this.state.items
}
```

So that the values are read-only when the condition is true i.e we have value inside the object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `this.state.items` starts out as an empty array (which is strange, since later on it looks like its an object) You first need to make sure `this.state.items.content` is defined

Do it like this:

```
console.log(this.state.items.content && this.state.items.content.length);
```

Or in your actual case

```
if(this.state.items.content && this.state.items.content.length > 0){
    //access values from this.state.items
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

The state is being initialized as an array but you're accessing `content` (which is `undefined`):

```
{
  loading: true,
  error: false,
  items: []
};
```

To avoid making an further changes, initialize the state so it follows the same structure as the response. For example:

```
{
  loading: true,
  error: false,
  items: { content: [] }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember that in the first render your items array is empty and the prop content doesnt exist. So maybe you have to check the length after you ve been fetched the data correctly:

```
  componentDidMount() {
        fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/v2/pages/1')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => this.setState({ items: data , itemsLength: data.content.length}));
    }
```

so when you want to check the lenght  you have to check that **this.state.itemsLength**  is different from null or from the initial state.

Answer (score 0):

During first render the items array is empty and as such when you try to access the property content of items it doesn't exist that's why you get the undefined error. to overcome this, you first of all check for it presence before calculating the length. ie

`if (this.state.items.content && (this.state.items.content.length > 0))`

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind the order of lifecycle function calls in a React Component. During the initial mounting phase, `render()` is called before `componentDidMount()`. So then, the first time your component is rendered, items is simply an empty array and items.content is undefined.

You could then write a condition like so:

```
if (this.state.items.content !== undefined && this.state.items.content.length > 0) {
    //access values from this.state.items
}
```